# How to set property "android:drawableTop" of a button at runtime

Tags: android, layout

How to set property "`android:drawableTop`" of a button at runtime

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Use

`button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);`

Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use 0 if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

If you use

`button.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);`

Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use null if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables must already have had [setBounds(Rect)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds%28android.graphics.Rect%29) called.

Comment: The method is very much correct but I want to set Resource id in place of drawable. Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: Yes.Use Resources resources= getResources();
Drawable drawable= resources.getDrawable(id);

Comment: Tanmay, I'm trying to do this too and I'm still not sure how to set drawableTop using the code.  I see how to get a drawable, but how to set it on the button?

Comment: Is there a reason why this would not work in the ExpandableListView Group name ? This was the trick I wanted to use to put the group indicator on the right instead of the left.

Comment: Thanks just to clarify I used. b.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.drawable.x,0,0);

Comment: getDrawable() is now deprecated

Answer (score 57):

```
Drawable top = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, top , null, null);
```

Answer (score 23):

```
final Drawable drawableTop = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_check_buttonless_on);

btnByCust.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


 btnByCust.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawableTop , null, null);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: The method is very much correct but I want to set Resource id in place of drawable. Is there any way to do the same.

Comment: @Maneesh Check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for the method

Answer (score 2):

I use this code for use the "Theme.Holo" button with a "Custom image" at left and change it (the image)with a function that is called from various ways.

```
protected void app_dibujarLogojuego() {
    if(bitmaplogojuego!=null){
        bitmaplogojuego.recycle();
        bitmaplogojuego=null;
    }
    Drawable LOGO = null;
    if(verjuego.equals("COSA1")){  LOGO = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_logo_COSA1);  }
    if(verjuego.equals("COSA2")){  LOGO = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_logo_COSA2);  }
    if(verjuego.equals("COSA3")){  LOGO = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_logo_COSA3);  }
    if(verjuego.equals("COSA4")){  LOGO = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_logo_COSA4);  }

    BUTTON_DECLARED_ID.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(LOGO, null , null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image_name_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, you can use extension method to make things look elegant.

```
fun TextView.setDrawableTop(iconId: Int) {
    val icon = this.context?.resources?.getDrawable(iconId)
    this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, icon, null, null)
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// myTextView: TextView
myTextView.setDrawableTop(R.drawable.ic_happy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension function like this and set top `drawable` like this

```
tvAccepted.setTopDrawable(R.drawable.ic_preparing_order_active)

fun TextView.setTopDrawable(icon: Int) {
    this.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,icon,0,0)
}
```

where

`setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(left/start, top, right/end, bottom)`