# How to set drawable(with changed size) in button like android:drawableTop at Runtime

Tags: android, button, drawable

I am fetching number of images and text related to it from server
Now i want to set each image with text(at bottom) in LinearLayout

I got the answer of second part of the question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919703/how-to-set-property-androiddrawabletop-of-a-button-at-runtime)

`button.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);`

But problem with this is I am getting images of different sizes and want to resize them

I am succeded to resizing Button by using Layout Params but with

`setCompoundDrawable(left,top,right,bottom);` image doesnt get resized

How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below code was working for you Because Its work fine with me

```
   Bitmap bitmap = ImageResizeUtility.resizeBitmap(bitmap, 100, 110);
```

Use this class to resize the images

```
public class ImageResizeUtility
{

    public static Bitmap resizeBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap, final int width, final int height)
    {
        final int oldWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        final int oldHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        final int newWidth = width;
        final int newHeight = height;

        // calculate the scale
        final float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
        final float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;

        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the Bitmap
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // if you want to rotate the Bitmap

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        final Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Hi i am creating bitmap from drawable and at the time of applying your code it gives me height and width of bitmap as -1. Is my implementation correct? i am using ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(); to get bitmap from drawable

Comment: have you check that bitmap is not null. It is possible that if bitmap is not available than it was return height and width null.

Comment: If the code is helpful to you than please check accept sign at the left corner. Thanks user557157