# Android - How to set Text Color on a button with ✔ as text on Android M

Tags: android, button, android-6.0-marshmallow, textcolor, android-text-color

On Android M

```
button.setText("✔");
button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Does not work any idea why?

How can i get the ✔ white colored?

Comment: your code is proper it's working in my code.

Comment: it does not work on Android M only, tried on samsung s7 and emulator with android 6 and on both is bugged, on older versions of android worked normally

Comment: i was tried it's working fine in my emulator with os Mars mellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unicode also for tick mark,Try to use `&#x2713;` with string and set it to your textview.

Comment: Thank you,the one you suggested works but i wanted this ✔ if possible

Comment: @KristiyanPetrov glad to help you happy coding

Answer (score 1):

try doing this way,

in your xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hint="hii" />
</LinearLayout >
```

Now, in your java file add this code like

```
public class SixthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_activity);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setText("");
        btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: read better my question... 

my question was how to get this ✔ in white on Android M

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can add drawables to view. Like that in xml :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load More"
    android:id="@+id/loadMore"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_marked_icon"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/another_icon_if_need"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Also in your code you can do like that :

```
Drawable top = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
//placement is like that : left, top, right, bottom
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, top , null, null);
```

I take this solution in : [How to set property “android:drawableTop” of a button at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919703/how-to-set-property-androiddrawabletop-of-a-button-at-runtime)

Also you can change drawable's tint value like that:

```
public static Drawable setTint(Drawable d, int color) {
    Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, color);
    return wrappedDrawable;
}
```

this solution based on : [change color of drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

Comment: if possible i would like to avoid using a drawable to solve this problem

Comment: i understand, but this is like another possible solution.