# how to set drawabletop programmatically in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a button in Xamarin android with an image above it. doing some googling i found that there is something in the axml u can use called drawabletop. however my buttons are created programmatically, so in want to know how i can fill in this parameter outside of the axml. button.drawabletop does not exist.

```
 private async void LoadCardList(string code)
    {
        CardDataService cardDataService = new CardDataService(new CardRepo());
        Cards = await cardDataService.GetCardsAsync(code);

        TableLayout ll = View.FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.cardlist);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        var i = 0;
        var row = new TableRow(this.Activity);
        row.WeightSum = 2;

        var sortedCards = Cards.OrderBy(o => o.number).ToList();

        foreach (var cards1 in sortedCards)
        {
            var b = new Button(this.Activity);
            b.Text = cards1.name;

            lp.Weight = 1;
            b.LayoutParameters = lp;
            row.AddView(b);
            i++;
            if (i > 1)
            {
                ll.AddView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent));
                row = new TableRow(this.Activity);
                row.LayoutParameters = lp;
                i = 0;
            }

        }
```

this is my method where i do everything. those buttons i create are the ones i want to have an image. the sortedCards list also contains an image.

regards,

Bjorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
b.SetCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
```

or

```
b.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

as mentioned here: 
[How to set property "android:drawableTop" of a button at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919703/how-to-set-property-androiddrawabletop-of-a-button-at-runtime)